# Datatable in R Shiny: Read out marked cell from datatable with the KeyTable Extension with the help of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have another JavaScript question. I use a DataTable with the keyTable extension.
This extension marks a single cell and you can navigate through the table with the arrow keys.

I want to read out, what cell is selected anytime. I think the easiest way is to do it with JavaScript, but I am an absolute beginner with JS, so you have to help me.

Code like

```
"table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){",
"  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
"  if(key == 13 && targetName == 'body'){",
"      Shiny.setInputValue('Ausgaben_zelle_aenderung', cell.node());",
"  }",
"});",
"table.on('key-focus', function(e, datatable, cell, originalEvent){",
"  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
"  var type = originalEvent.type;",
"  if(type == 'keydown' && targetName == 'input'){",
"    if([9,13,37,38,39,40].indexOf(originalEvent.keyCode) > -1){",
"      Shiny.setInputValue('Ausgaben_zelle_aenderung', cell.node());",
"    }",
"  }",
"});"
```

gives me the information what cell is selected, while I'm in the editing mode. This works. I want to modify this code to get the cell information when I don't change the value. So I tried to adapt the code, but code like

```
"table.on('key', function(e, datatable, key, cell, originalEvent){",
"  if([9,13,37,38,39,40].indexOf(key) > -1){",
"      Shiny.setInputValue('test1', cell.node());",
"  }",
"});"
```

is not working. Can you help me?

With best regards
Chefkoch

Comment: If I correctly understand what you want, I would try to remove `&& targetName == 'input'` in the `key-focus` event handler. (You should always provide a minimal reproducible example, so that someone who wants to help you can give a try).

Comment: it could be so easy! Thank you very much, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
"table.on('key-focus', function(e, datatable, cell, originalEvent){",
"  var targetName = originalEvent.target.localName;",
"  var type = originalEvent.type;",
"  if(type == 'keydown' && targetName == 'input'){",
"    if([9,13,37,38,39,40].indexOf(originalEvent.keyCode) > -1){",
"      Shiny.setInputValue('Ausgaben_zelle_aenderung', cell.node());",
"    }",
"  }",
"});"
```

`targetName` is the type of the element in which the key has been pressed. It is an `input` when you are in editable mode. So, if you want always to get the cell info, remove the `targetName == 'input'` test:

```
"table.on('key-focus', function(e, datatable, cell, originalEvent){",
"  var type = originalEvent.type;",
"  if(type == 'keydown'){",
"    if([9,13,37,38,39,40].indexOf(originalEvent.keyCode) > -1){",
"      Shiny.setInputValue('Ausgaben_zelle_aenderung', cell.node());",
"    }",
"  }",
"});"
```